# Relay-style pagination with Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django 3.x app (with Django REST Framework) and I need to expose a REST API that will then be consumed by a GraphQL server in order to provide a GraphQL endpoint to a client.

The [cursor based pagination provided by Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#cursorpagination) out of the box only provides a `next` and `previous` cursors for each request, but Relay [requires one opaque cursor for each returned edge/item](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm).

How can I ask Django REST Framework to generate a cursor for each item?

Comment: Django doesn't provide cursor-based pagination. Django REST Framework does. The distinction is important.

Comment: If [GraphQL Cursor Connections Specification](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm) is the spec you're talking about, I'm not sure I see how it would require a cursor per item..?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, it looks like the [implementation for CursorPagination](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/98e56e0327596db352b35fa3b3dc8355dc9bd030/rest_framework/pagination.py#L577) is basically an encoding of an unique-ish attribute + a "lesser than"/"greater than" query. If that helps...

Comment: I added a link to the Relay spec. Each edge is an item, and each edge has a cursor.

Comment: Right, that's the same spec I linked. :) Either way – how are you interfacing the queries from the GraphQL server to DRF? The reason why edges have a cursor in that spec is that you could paginate over a "sub-collection" in a query, but that's not really a specified thing in REST.

Comment: my case is much simpler, I just need cursors to start fetching data from any item of the list.

Comment: Then I'd suggest encoding the primary key of each item as the opaque cursor string and subclassing the default related fields into something that exposes that `cursor` value along with the item data.